# Seeking update for QMarxan plugin of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Is there a QGIS 2.4 update for the QMarxan plugin which at this stage only works on version 1.8.0?

I did read on one forum that this was in the process of being developed.

Answer (score 2):

The QMarxan plugin is now deprecated and the new **QMarxanZ** plugin is suggested to be used for version of QGIS from 2.8 and above: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QMarxanZ/

Here's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/tsw-apropos/qmarxanz

Answer (score 1):

According to their [homepage](http://www.aproposinfosystems.com/products/qmarxan/) they are working on it.

> "Qmarxan currently only works with QGIS 1.8. We are working on an
>   updated plugin that compatible for QGIS 2.0 and hope to release in by
>   early 2014. "

However there haven't been any pushes to their [github repository](https://github.com/tsw-apropos/qmarxan) since 5 months, so you might want to ask them directly if they still working on it

Answer (score 1):

An update on this.
The original developers of the QMarxan plugin have developed the **QMarxan Toolbox**, working with recent versions of QGIS:

- info: https://aproposinfosystems.com/solutions/qmarxan-toolbox/
- GitHub repo: https://github.com/tsw-apropos/qmarxantoolbox

**CLUZ** is another very good plugin to work with Marxan:

- info: https://anotherbobsmith.wordpress.com/software/cluz/
- GitHub repo: https://github.com/AnotherBobSmith/CLUZ/